# Anchor how to unpack account data with trdelnik

Tags: anchor, solana, anchor-solana

In Anchor with a trdelnik test I am trying to unpack a retrieved account and check with an *eq!* if account state is updated accordingly. Can anyone help me with achieving this?

```
let account_state = fixture
    .client
    .get_account(fixture.auction_account.pubkey())
    .await?
    .unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing it in an unchecked way.

```
let account_state = solana_sdk::borsh::try_from_slice_unchecked::<Auction>(account_state.data.borrow());
```